# SQL Installation Error In Memory, Can i just add a database to an existing SQL Instance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

We have an SBS server running 4 Microsoft SQL 2008R2 instances. I need another for an anti-spam product, but the install fails with an error about possible corrupt memory. I've done some digging and re-installing all the instances isn't an issue so can I just add a new database to an existing SQL Instance to get this running?

Comment: Most likely yes, but I would confirm with the product vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have so many SQL instances? I'm not a DBA, but normally I've only seen named instances for situations where you're trying to run multiple environments on a single DB server (for example a dev and stage version of the same DB).

To answer your question, yes there should be no problem at all to add as many DBs as you need to any instances.